# Ruby Selenium Unable to get value of h4 tag

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am unable to get the value of `<h4>` tag in selenium ruby code.

Here is my selectors config.yml

```
selectors:
  - Topix_Header_Div:
    - selector: ".local-news"
    - type: 'css'
    - element: 'div'
  - Topix_Header_Div:
    - selector: ".local-news .comp-header"
    - type: 'css'
    - element: 'div'
  - Topix_Header_Heading:
    - selector: ".local-news .comp-header h4"
    - type: 'css'
    - element: 'heading'
```

The  tag is inside nested divs like below.

```
<div class="local-news">
 <div class="comp-header">
  <h4>Local News - Buffalo, NY</h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

Below is my Ruby Code.

```
on (@pageName) do |page|
    page.wait_until(3, "Could not find location") do
        not page.Topix_Header_Heading_element.text.empty?
    end
    expect(page.Topix_Header_Heading).to eq(location)
end
```

This is the output I am getting.

```
 Could not find results (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError)
```